# Could not find the specific lines of code to edit in an R function?

Tags: r

I am using "hydrogeo" package in R for piper plots. I want to make some edits in the function for customization of plots.

Hydrogeo package has following functions

`"piper"      "piperPaper"        "plot"       "testData"    "toPercent"`

In this particular package I want to customize the plots bu changing line type, and polygon color. However, while calling any of the function in

```
trace("piper", edit=TRUE)
```

I do not get the specific line of code where I can make the edits and the command returns following lines

```
function (d, ...) 
{
  new("piper", d, call = sys.call(), ...)
}
```

Is there any way to edit specific lines of the function?

Comment: You can copy the source code of the function, do necessary changes and then make it as your new custom function?

Comment: You can find the source code here https://github.com/cran/hydrogeo/blob/master/R/piper.R. Copy and paste the source code and make necessary changes within it.

Comment: Where to copy and paste the source code to edit it, once I have installed the package?
Should I need to download the package and make the edits and install it from local directory?
Is there any way to modify already installed package for Hydrogeo?

Comment: Don't try to edit the installed package. Even if you succeed, you may break some other functionality of the package. The edit will also disappear if you update the package.

Comment: @Rohit what is the solution then? I need to modify the plot styling to make it more appealing and informative.

Comment: @dSb, I suggest going through the link provided by Bappa. If you can, try editing the code there and saving it with different names. Otherwise, start from scratch and use a different package like `ggplot2` to recreate it.